# Increase group width horizontally in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

This is probably a simple answer but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I am trying to increase the width of the "dividers" for the group sections in the picture below. Notice how the page headers and footers extend further to the right and will increase dynamically to the landscape format.

[image]
Crystal reports group width (as above image shown
If I select fields and try to move them over, they will shrink at the border. Is there any way to increase the group width to allow for more fields/columns?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Normally it should increase automatically...do one thing convert the whole report to protrait and then change to landscape

Comment: Hi @Siva , do you mean just going into page setup and going to portrait and back to landscape again? Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean...does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not doing the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only cross-tab gives the facility to dynamically growth on right side based on your run-time data.

No other way you can achive. By the way why you want to grow on right side.

Simple logic is : When you design crystal report (as we already know the layout), we give the page size and accordingly we set the fields and layout. If you though, the A4 page size is not enough, you can achieve this via A3 page size or more and while printing you give A4 size. There is no conflict with page size while printing means if we design with A3 page, by default A3 is best, but we print on A4 too.

Crystal report by default vertical increase with simple fields and group. As well as fields also increase with can grow option, but increase vertically again. Are you try that?

There is no logic to grow horizontally in group.

Comment: I'll try the can grow option. Thanks!